# show application icon without saving icon value in data base

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to display the application icon in a React Native app based on the package name and application name retrieved from an SQLite database, without storing the icon value in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this package react-native-dynamic-app-icon
https://github.com/idearockers/react-native-dynamic-app-icon

but it's limited.

Comment: react-native-dynamic-app-icon
Programmatically change the app icon in React Native